# Azure APIM Developer Portal Access via Okta

Tags: azure-api-management, okta

How can Azure APIM Developer Portal access be secured with Okta?
(I'm aware of the "Azure AD B2C + Okta" scenario and that is not what I am looking for). It seems that MS suggests [Delegate Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-setup-delegation) but it is unclear how to set up delegation endpoints on okta side.